# dialog box disappears quickly after ringing an alarm - android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i created a program that will ring an alarm if it received a message even when phone is locked. when the phone rings, it will show dismiss button to stop the alarm, but my code just shows the dismiss button and disappears quickly leaving me with no option on how to stop the alarm. please help me with this code. thanks for help in advance

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receiverinterface);
    unlockScreen();
    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alarm");
            alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Stop Alarm")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    Ringtone r = EAlarmReceiver.r;
                    r.stop();
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(EAlarmReceiver.sms.length() > 10)
                    {
                        Intent openInterface = new Intent("proj.receiver.VIEWMESSAGE");
                        openInterface.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(openInterface);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent openInterface = new Intent("proj.receiver.RECEIVERINTERFACE");
                        openInterface.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(openInterface);
                    }
                }
            });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
}// end oncreate()

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

//unlock screen
public void unlockScreen() {
    //make the activity show even the screen is locked.
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

Comment: I don't know the context of your application, but usually there is no reason to call `finish()` on the activity in the `onPause()` method. Remove that method and check again.

Comment: it worked fine. but i am using a transparent alertdialog so when i removed the onpause(), i am left with a transparent activity so i am forced to use the home button. i don't know how to solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code after removing `finish()` from onPause(). post complete code too.

Edit :- As you said removing finish worked for you, here is solution of your second question.

1) Complex and temporary solution :- try to add a boolean variable, which u should set to true on action taken on AlertDialog, and if it is true in onResume , finish ur activity. OnResume calls each time u comes back to ur activity.

2) But if i were at ur place, i would have followed below approach.

Create a layout looks like alert Dialog. and setup Activity theme as Dialog in activity declaration in manifest, it will open ur activity as dialog. hence u need not to create an AlertDialog to handle action, u can add buttons for dismiss and all.

Comment: it worked fine. but i am planning to finish() this activity after i've gone to another activity after pressing dismiss button. i'm using a transparent alertdialog so when i removed finish(), i am left with a single transparent activity and i'm forced to use the home button to gain access of the phone.

Comment: try to add a boolean variable, which u should set to true on action taken on AlertDialog, and if it is true in onResume , finish ur activity. OnResume calls each time u comes back to ur activity.